# Increase Raycaster size in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically what I'm trying to do is to use rays in Three.js to detect for objects on my screen.

But the problem is that I have a lot of objects on the screen and not all of them are being detected and if I use too many rays, it becomes very slow and sometimes my browser even crash.

So I was thinking if there is a way to actually increase the size of the rays or something similar to that.

Comment: For a start, google `octree` and have a look at http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree.html and http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree_raycasting.html. Also google `GPU Picking` -- there is a three.js example of that, too.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you, this will be useful. I'll have a look at it.